# Learning F# with style

Tags: f#, coding-style

When passing a function to another function which should calculate the result and then pass that value  as an  argument to another function, I've discovered that I could "compose" the following code in 5 different ways.

```
let testnum testFun =
    testFun 4

printfn "result: %b" (testnum (=) 0)  

printfn "result: %b" <| testnum (<) 0

printfn "result: %b" (testnum <| (>=) 0)

testnum <|  (=) 0 |> printfn "result: %b"

printfn "resutl: %b" << testnum <| (<>) 0
```

I do like the style without parentheses more but now I'm wondering, is there a preferred style assuming my goal is *readability* and *supportability* of my code?

Comment: You could even do this: `(fun x -> x = 0) |> testnum |> printfn "result: %b"`

Comment: This might be better for codereview - not sure.

Comment: usually F#ers like the forward pipes `|>` as here the type-inference just works better so go with the version @Gary.S proposed

Comment: I think in this case simplest variant (1st) is better. It is shorter and more readable than others. There is no need for any kind of pipes here.

Comment: @Petr I agree.  I generally use piping when the parts of the expression are complex.  In this case, each part is simple, so there isn't a need to break it up to comprehend its meaning.

Comment: Assuming your goal is **readability** and **supportability** of your code, there's an objective answer (hence my reopen vote; rollback if disagree). Although all variants are *syntactically correct*, the idea is *threading a certain value through a chain of transformations*. E.g. requesting a DB: `userID |> getInvoicesByUser |> filter (fun invoice -> invoice.Amount > 100) |> Seq.sum`. This would clearly indicate all transformations of `userID` value. The "source data" is not a part of the computation, but the rest is. In your case, it would be `((=) 0) |> testnum |> printf "result: %b"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer pipe `|>`, this help with inference and readability

```
(=) 3 |> testnum |> printfn "result: %b"
```

you can easy break it on multiple lines

```
(=) 3
|> testnum
|> printfn "result: %b"
```

if arguments are few, you can pass them directly

```
testnum (=) 4 |> printfn "result: %b"
```

but use pipe `|>` or composition `>>` like `g x |> f` or `x |> g |> f` instead of nested function call  `f(g(x))`, is more idiomatic. This also help with inference, for example instead of the `.` operator

```
open System.Linq

let double x = x * 2

let double1 items = items |> Seq.map double
[1;2;3] |> double1 |> printfn "%A"

//this doesn't compile,
//error: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed ..
//
// let double2 items = items.Select(double)
// [1;2;3] |> double2 |> printfn "%A"

let double3 (items:seq<_>) = items.Select(double)
[1;2;3] |> double3 |> printfn "%A"
```

example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K0u3NQ

Answer (score 2):

For your example I would have picked the first one:

```
printfn "result: %b" (testnum (=) 0)
```

The second one is passable:

```
printfn "result: %b" <| testnum (<) 0
```

The others are too contrived, they look like exercise in obfuscation.

I do use "backward" pipe operator exclusively in two situations:

- when I have a type constructor that would need nested parentheses otherwise, so `Some <| Foo ("bar", "baz")` instead of `Some (Foo ("bar", "baz"))`
- when I want to pass a single anonymous function as a last argument - it communicates nicely where the action is at:

  ```
  lock sync <| fun () ->
      ...
  ```

  For what is worth, if there are multiple anonymous functions passed as arguments, I would usually parenthesize each one of them instead (the notable exception being when one of them is a few characters long one liner and the other has multiple lines - then I would still go with the above syntax).

As for pipelining, I would usually go with `|>` for longer pipelines, and use function composition `>>` for shorter ones, when I don't need to refer to the argument again in the body of the function.

I don't think I would ever put `|>` and `<|` in the same line without parenthesizing one of them. It just looks odd.